# Database query optimization question

Tags: database, query-optimization

Assumptions for question:

1. Database Agnostic
2. Both queries will return just one row due to the values of X and Y

Question:

Which query is faster, and is one a better practice?:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE X = 'some value' AND Y = 'other value';
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE X = 'some value';
```

Basically, do you benefit or lose (performance-wise) from passing extra unneeded parameters into a query, and if "benefit" is the answer, is it a "good" practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly the query with more parameters needs to do more work, but I think you will find in most cases that the difference will be so trivial as to make it a moot point.

The best practice is to write a query in such a way that solves your business problem and let the chips fall where they may. If you obviously know that a parameter is redundant then leave it off, if for no other reason than to simplify your code. However, I wouldn't spend a great deal of time going to look for situations where a parameter is redundant because of the current state of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance there shouldn't be a significant difference if your tables are indexed correctly.

- If column X has an index both queries will be fast.
- If neither column X nor Y is indexed both queries won't be that fast, but similar in speed (assuming that for most rows both conditions fail - then only one will be evaluated).
- If column Y is indexed but not X then the second query will be faster as it is the only one that can use the index on column Y.

One thing to be aware of is that the two queries might give different results if the values of X and Y are not what you expected. In the first case it will return the row even if the value of Y is different from what you expected. In the second case the row won't be returned at all. You should consider what you want to happen in this error situation and choose the query based on that decision. If you want to display an error `Expected value 'foo' for Y but found 'bar'` then you will need to fetch the row so the first query would be more suitable.

Comment: Both queries are supposed to return 1 result.

Comment: @XSaint32: Sure, but sometimes there can be a difference between what a query is *supposed* to do and what it *actually* does.

Comment: Agree 100%. I was just clarifying what the OP stated as his second assumption.

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answers, and assuming a correctly placed index, the better practice would be to state very specifically what you want. You can depend on the number of outcomes now, but thinking ahead in an evolving project and making sure that with changes your queries will stay as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on (X,Y) there should be no difference in speed if both queries really return the same amount of rows (if the second one returns more rows, then of course it will be slower)

If your index is the other way round i.e. defined as (Y,X) the second query might be substantially slower as that index is not usable for most DBMS.

I think Oracle 11g will be able to use the (Y,X) index even for the second query, but it will still be slower as a prefix match for the index.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, if both one-parameter query and two-parameters query fetch one row, and X is their common condition, the **AND Y = 'other value'** should not be a significant column in query optimizer.

Unless you need and only need Y as query condition for one row, index on Y is not a good practice in this example.

Index on X is the significant point in this example because one-parameter query should return 'one row'.

I think the database performance issue is about what you need and how you fetch needed row in lower I/O(Logical I/O, with implicit Physical I/O).

And the best practice, however, I also agree with **solving your business problem**.